# Número exato de vezes que determinado carácter deve repetir Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Olá, estou com um exercício de linguagens formais, do qual trabalhamos com Regex, o exercício consiste em validar uma cadeia que possui exatamente quatro 1s,
por exemplo:

cadeia 1: *0110101000* - **válida**;

cadeia 2: *010110* - **inválida**;

cadeia 3: *011011011* - **inválida**;

O que eu consegui fazer até agora, foi validar uma cadeia com quatro ou mais 1s, mas não consegui determinar exatamente o número de vezes que determinado carácter deve repetir:

Segue a expressão que consegui desenvolver até o momento: `/(\S*1){4}.*/`

Essa expressão valida cadeias com mais de quatro 1s, preciso validar uma cadeia que possua **exatamente** quatro 1s.

Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Os outros caracteres só podem ser zeros, ou podem ser qualquer outra coisa diferente de 1?*</sup>

---

Em todo caso, estou usando a expressão `[^1]` (tudo que não for `1`) em conjunto com `^` (início da string) e `$` (fim da string), para indicar que a regex tem que verificar toda a string, do início ao fim:

```
/^([^1]*1[^1]*){4}$/
```

Explicando:

- `[^1]*` - zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa diferente de `1` (para verificar o que vem antes do primeiro `1`)
- `1` - o próprio `1`
- `[^1]*` - zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa diferente de `1` (de novo, mas aqui é para verificar o que vem depois do último `1`)
- O quantificador `{4}` diz que a expressão anterior (tudo que está entre parênteses: `([^1]*1[^1]*)`) só pode se repetir quatro vezes

Veja ela funcionando [aqui](https://regexr.com/3rfsd).

---

Outra opção (já que a pergunta tem a tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) é contar a quantidade de ocorrências do caracter `1`, usando [`match`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp):

```js
// conta a quantidade de "1" na string
var quantidadeDeUm = ("01001001001".match(/1/g) || []).length;

console.log(quantidadeDeUm); // 4
```

Depois é só verificar se a quantidade é 4. A vantagem é que a regex é bem mais simples, e na minha opinião, fica um código bem mais fácil de entender e manter.

O trecho `|| []` retorna um array vazio, caso o `match` não encontre nenhuma ocorrência. Fiz isso porque quando não tem nenhuma ocorrência, o `match` retorna `null`, então neste caso eu uso um array vazio para não dar um [*TypeError: null*](https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript/null-undefined-properties).

Comment: Muito bom obrigado pela rápida resposta, ambas as opções supriram bem a minha necessidade, obrigado pelo apoio!!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui com a seguinte regex:

```
/^(0*10*){4}$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/sGa5mR/1

Em linguagens formais, é comum o uso de `0`s e `1`s. Senão eu ia frufruzar meu regex tb.

Outra forma de você fazer a mesma coisa sem quantificadores frufruzentos é assim:

```
/^0*10*10*10*10*$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/fYzNOc/1

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, ambas as repostas funcionaram da forma que eu necessitava.